# how to use Server Sent Event in different modules node?

Tags: node.js, server-sent-events

I am trying to leverage server sent event in node.js so my application can fire events to the browser for updating data on the page.

I have created three files
1. class carries server -sent method
2. route for streaming the request
3. Call of sseevent from that file

#### Server Sent Class

```
module.exports = function (req, res, next) {
    //SetTimeout
    //req.socket.setTimeout(Infinity);
    res.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'text/event-stream',
        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
        'Connection': 'keep-alive'
    });

    res.sseSend = function(data,event) {
        var d = new Date(),
            events = ((undefined === event) ? 'message' : event);
        res.write('id: ' + d.getMilliseconds() + '\n');
        res.write("data: " + JSON.stringify(data) + "\n\n");
        res.write("event:" + events);
    };
    next(); };
```

#### SSE route

```
import express from "express";
let router = express.Router();
import config from "../../config/configuration";
import sse from "../../class/server-sentEvent.class";


class ServerSent {
    constructor(app) {
        this.app = app;
        this.init();
    }

    init() {
        this.setupBase();
        this.sseEvent();
    }

    setupBase() {
        this.app.use(sse);
        this.app.use(config.basePath, router);
    }

    sseEvent(){
        let _this = this;
        router.get('/stream', function(req, res) {
            res.sseSend({'name':'FirstUser'},'update');
        });
    }
}

module.exports = (app) => {
    return new ServerSent(app);
};
```

#### Calling File

```
import express from "express";
    let router = express.Router();
    import config from "../../config/configuration";
    import sse from "../../class/server-sentEvent.class";

class Read {
    constructor(app) {
        this.app = app;

        this.init();
    }

    init() {
        this.getSecondUser();
    }

    getSecondUser() {
        router.post('/getAll', (req, res, next) => {
           res.sseSend({'name':'SecondUser'},'update');
           res.json(response);
        });
    }
}
```

From Read Class, ssesend Event is not getting fired not able figure out a way to do it.

Things I tried:

1. I tried to use event emitter that doesn't worked out
2. Tried using global variable.